# Laravel and Entity-Relationship Model - How far should I go?

Tags: database, entity-relationship, laravel, eloquent, third-normal-form

Some people maybe know ER-Diagrams? The model of a database

e.g.:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

So here is my database model:
[image]
(Translation: Werkstatt = Garage, Dienstleistung = Service, Kategorie = Category, Bewertung = Rating, bewerten = rate, besitzt = owns, hat = has)

My questions are:

**1)** I can model many-to-many relationships, one-to-one, one-to-many. Should I use own tables for them when needed? For example MANY-to-MANY relationship needs an own table. 
Or will Laravel take care of the relationship by its Eloquent ORM?

**2)** You can design a database so good, that there can't be NULL-Values for example. Or that it handles dependencies or redundancy in a proper way (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms). Should I take care of redundancy and dependancy, or will again Laravel take care of that?

So in general I just want to know, how far should I go with my database design? Should I make it as good as possible, or is it enough just to create the basic entities?

Info: Here you can see the consquences which can happen if the database is not normalized:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Free_the_database_of_modification_anomalies

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there should be no direct relationship between USER and GARAGE. Rather, one USER should be be linked to RATING (one to many), and GARAGE to RATING (again, one to many). So I would have Ratings as a separate table, with each rating having a userid, a garageid, and a rating. I believe that in that case, you will not need a separate many-to-many table, unless you count the rating as the many-to-many table (which you shouldn't--Rating should have its own Eloquent model, in fact.) Disclaimer: I'm just a beginner at Laravel myself.

Comment: I modelled rating as a field of garage. Every garage has an own rating and rating is just a value (integer or double). So why make an own table of rating? And despite that I have a bigger database model maybe in the future. Not only those four. So how exactly can I know where to use an own table or not? That is the reason why there is basic ER-Modelling and database normalization...

Comment: You said that every garage can be rated by many users. Is the garage's own rating the _average_ rating from each user? I had intended that the rating table would contain each user's individual rating; of course you could put the average rating as a value for garage, but how would you track the separate user ratings, if not in a separate table?

Comment: Nah, I dont need to track the ratings. I just want to know the total rating of all users for one garage ;)

Comment: What exactly is a rating? Maybe I'm confused about that. To me, a rating would be something like a number between 1 and 5. If you don't track the ratings, how do you handle it when an additional rating comes in? Are you just tracking the number of ratings, without paying attention to the value? What happens if a user wants to change their rating?

Comment: the total average rating... yes its a number between 1 and 5 for example... 1st user rates with 1 the other user rates with 5... so rating of the garage will be 3... but the question is another anyway ;-)